# Java: Subclass class and its subclass (both out of my scope) at the same time

Tags: java, subclass, extends, repeat

Given two classes, one subclasses the other, both out of my scope, so I don't have any influence on them, eg.

```
public class Bla {
}

public class SubBla extends Bla {
}
```

How can I create a customized subclass of Bla and SubBla without repeating code or limit SubBla's special functionalities?

Edit: So I don't have to:

```
public class MyBla extends Bla {
    public void someOverriddenMethodOfBla()
    {
        super.someOverriddenMethodOfBla();
        // do something custom
    }
}

public class MySubBla extends SubBla {

    // repeated code: this should do the same as MyBla's customized method
    public void someOverriddenMethodOfBla()
    {
        super.someOverriddenMethodOfBla();
        // do the same custom stuff as in MyBla's method
    }

}
```

Edit 2, to clear things up a litte:

Let's say I need the android classes Activity and ListActivity, which is a subclass of Activity. Now I want to add the **same** customization in the onCreate method to **both**. How do I acomplish this without repeating code?

Thanks!

Comment: The purpose of subclassing is reuse..so that you dont repeat code (however, you can override/overload) ...can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: you dont require `MyBla` class at all. If `B extends A` then if you subclass `B` by `C extends B`...`C **IS** A also!` you dont require `C extends A` and again `D extends B`. So in your example all you require is `MySubla extends Subbla`

Comment: No, I also need MyBla directly. That's the problem ;)

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example what you cannot do with MySubBla that you can only do with MyBlah?

Comment: SubBla overrides other methods of Bla, which do a completely different thing. So I can't use MySubBla in cases where I need the special functionallities of MyBla and vice versa

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to bypass `SubBla`'s implementation, and invoke `Bla`'s implementation directly from a subclass of `SubBla`. What you're trying to do is essentially call `super.super`, which cannot be done in Java

There's a good explanation for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586363/why-is-super-super-method-not-allowed-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

Actually the purpose of inheritance is that you reuse code. In java there only exists public inheritance which means that the accessibility of the methods will remain the same trough inheritance.

If you do MyBla extends Bla then all public methods from Bla will remain still visible in the MyBla class.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your example for Android `Activity` and `ListActivity`, subclass `ListActivity` as `CustomListActivity`. In `CustomListActivity` add your version of `onCreate()`. Now instead of using `Activity` or `ListActivity` you use `CustomListActivity` in your application.

Comment: But I also need to use the customized normal activity, how to do that?

Comment: I am sorry I have no idea about Android API...I dont think I understand your comment.. Let me give a shot: So you have `Activity`, `ListActivity` and `CustomListActivity`. You instantiate the one that is appropriate for example: if you have a Class `A` that can do with `onCreate()` from `Activity`, instantiate `Activity activity = new Activity();` If you want Class `B` that requires to use your custom `onCreate()` you instantiate `Activity customListActivity = new CustomListActivity();` and use this instance.

Comment: No, I need Activity and ListActivity, both with customized onCreate for example

Comment: You probably might want to take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419758/inject-new-methods-and-properties-into-classes-during-runtime

Comment: IMHO you can do it but Java API(version 6) does not provide out-of-the-box solution for this.

Comment: now you got me ;) thx, but that's too much of a hack. i'll stick to the repeated code thing until i find something neater