# Add new methods during runtime

Tags: javascript

Is there any way we can add new methods during run-time.

In Java we can do this **[stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1419776/1328612)**

I just want to know it's possible by just doing using JavaScript?

Comment: yes you can - in fact _everything_ is added at runtime, because Javascript is interpreted so there is no real compile-time like in Java!

Comment: Describe your use case, or any sample code?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is dynamic and there is no compilation involved (other than JIT compiling in the browser, maybe), so things like these are actually trivial and need to happen at runtime:

`someObject.newMethod = function(s) { console.log("haha") }`

This adds a new method `newMethod` to an object `someObject`.
Using the prototype you can add methods to more than just one instance in one step - they will be immediately available to all instances of that prototype.

Answer (score 0):

function are first class citizens in JavaScript.
Execute the following code from Chrome and see the console output;

In the first time the will see the error "TypeError: undefined id not a function" because hello function does not exist.

In the second time no error and we will get "Hello Exits "

```js
var object = {};

try {
    object.hello("Does not exit");
}
catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
}

object.hello = function(name){
   console.log("Hello " + name);
}

try {
    object.hello("Exits");
    console.log("No error");
}
catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean adding code dynamically?

It's actually easier to do this in javascript.
It can be done using the `eval` function.

usage:

```
eval('code to be run');
```

example:

### HTML

```
<p id="para">this is a paragraph</p>
```

### javascript

```
eval('document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "this is a changed paragraph"');
```

notice how the javascript inside the `eval` function is a string.
`eval` takes a string and evaluates it as javascript.

**Warning**, assuming you are using javascript on the client-side this is extremely discouraged.
`eval` will take and run code from anywhere and it is considered a security risk.
If you are using `use strict` then eval is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

In JavaScript, we have functions are first-class objects and you can manipulate them easily. Combined with the fact that objects are prototype based and not class-based, you can easily add a method to an object. Or to an object's prototype :

```
//add function to one object :

var object = {};

object.sayHello = function(){
  alert("hello");
};

object.sayHello();

//add function to a prototype

//our constructor
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;    
}

var p = new Person("John", "Doe");

Person.prototype.sayMyName=function(){
  alert("My name is "+this.firstName+ " " + this.lastName);
};

//now all persons can say their name

p.sayMyName();

p2 = new Person("Isaac", "Newton");

p2.sayMyName();
```

Play with is on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/mohusodeqa/4/edit)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't have `compile` stage that produces a `.class` file. The JS code is interpreted by the browser at runtime. Adding a dynamic function is so easy that it's very hard to remember/find how many functions are available on an object.

For example, there is an object `globalObj` in the globe scope. In file `a.js`:

```
globalObj.a = function () { console.log('from a.js'.); }
```

In file `b.js`:

```
globalObj.b = function () { console.log('from b.js'.); }
```

In a project with hundreds of JS files, you may easily get lost. IDEs are also facing the same problem.