# Java Logger, log a list of messages

Tags: java, csv, logging

I got the following method

```
    public static boolean isCSVStructureValid(InputStream csv, InputStream csvSchema){

    boolean failFast = true;
    boolean trace = false;
    Reader csvReader = new InputStreamReader(csv);
    Reader csvSchemaReader = new InputStreamReader(csvSchema);
    List<Substitution> pathSubtitution = new ArrayList<>();
    List<FailMessage> messages = CsvValidator.validate(csvReader, csvSchemaReader, failFast,
                       pathSubtitution,true, trace);
    if (messages.isEmpty()){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "The CSV stream structure is invalid: {0}", messages);
        return false;
    }
}
```

How can I log the content of the message stored inside the List messages? 
This is the JavaDoc of the type FailMessage: http://javadox.com/uk.gov.nationalarchives/csv-validator-java-api/1.0-RC2/uk/gov/nationalarchives/csv/validator/api/java/FailMessage.html

Currently I got this output:

```
SEVERE: The CSV stream structure is invalid: [uk.gov.nationalarchives.csv.validator.api.java.ErrorMessage@1a4927d6]
```

Whereas I would like to see something more useful such as:

```
SEVERE: The CSV stream structure is invalid: [3.6] failure: Invalid column definition

User ID: positiveInteger

     ^
```

That I can obtain by doing this:

```
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "The CSV stream structure is invalid: {0}", messages.get(0).getMessage());
```

Comment: If you have a `List` and want to do something (e.g. call `getMessage()`) on each element, you .... loop over the elements. You have heard of [`for` loops](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html), right? Yeah, of course you have. So I guess I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I know that, but how do you do that in an elegant way when logging?

Comment: `LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "The CSV stream structure is invalid:"); for (FailMessage message : messages) LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "  " + message.getMessage());`? Aka **loop**.

Comment: messages.forEach(m -> LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE,m.getMessage()));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see the class does not override the default `Object.toString()`. If you follow your link you will see in the javadoc.

You have several options to overcome this problem:

1. The easiest is to override that method:
   You modify this class if you can. But I guess you use it as an API.
   In this case consider to issue a pull request to their repository:
   https://github.com/digital-preservation/csv-validator/pulls
2. You can create a helper method that returns a `String` by iterating through the objects, call the `getMessage()` and appending the result to a `StringBuilder`
3. You can create a custom Formatter for the Logger, see the `java.util.logging.Formatter.format(java.util.logging.LogRecord)`
   I assume you use this logging framework.
4. An advanced solution is to use bytecode modification.
   [Inject New Methods and Properties into Classes During Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419758/inject-new-methods-and-properties-into-classes-during-runtime)

Hope you can find a good solution for yourself from the list above.

Answer (score 1):

The elegant solution is:

```
            messages.forEach(m -> LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE,m.getMessage()));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, ErrorMessage does not overridden toString method to give proper message as what you expected. When you know that it is stored as list, if you can get the list and iterate though them