# Create POJO and populate it from Map<String, String>

Tags: java, spring, class, reflection

At runtime I want to create a POJO with attributes that are same as keys of the map and populate it with the values of the map.
 ***I don't know the content of the map or what the POJO will look like***.
**Example**-

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.add("attr1", obj1);
map.add("attr2", obj2);
...
```

From this map I want to create a POJO-

```
class POJO
{
    String attr1;

    public void setAttr1(String attr1) {
        this.attr1 = attr1;
    }

    public String getAttr1() {
        return attr1;
    }

    String attr2;

    public void setAttr2(String attr2) {
        this.attr2 = attr2;
    }

    public String getAttr2() {
        return attr2;
    }

    .....
}
```

and populate it as well.
All of this should happen at runtime.
Something like-

```
Object object = getPopulatedPOJO(map)
```

or

```
Class type = getPOJOType(map);
Object object = type.newInstance();
object = getPopulatedPOJO(map)
```

Comment: What's your goal after the POJO is populated? This may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @JacobG. I have to send it to a third party, the API of which accepts only java objects.

Comment: What format do these Java objects have to be in for the API to accept it? JSON? Because if so, what you're really asking here is: "How do I convert a `Map<String, Object>` to JSON?"

Comment: why this might not be a [good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1419776/4214241)

Comment: @R.G : I don't want to modify existing Java class. I want to create a new one.

Comment: Your `map` is still a Java object, why would you need to make it into a POJO at runtime?

Comment: @Nexevis because the API accepts POJO's

Comment: POJO is a little bit generic. Can you link the swagger of that API?

Comment: You mean that you want a POJO object with a variable number of field and at runtime you create those fields?

Comment: @Marvin: this does not answer my question because I don't know what my POJO will be!

Comment: It will be helpful if you can share what that API does ? Will it go through all the methods of the class starting with a get and invoke it to get the value ?

Comment: API accepts POJO as what? as Object? or as JSON/String? It looks possible using some bytecode manipulation

Comment: Who is providing this `getPOJOType` method? Who decides which type this method will return?

Comment: @Holger : It is my custom method....the one that i need to write.....it can return any class with the attributes that are same as the `keyset()` of the map

Answer (score 1):

This is not the final answer to your problem. But I hope this gives the direction you might want to continue with. Note that, this direction modifies bytecode instructions at runtime and can cause crashes and failures.

You can use `javassist` which is a bytecode manipulator. Please see their [official site](http://www.javassist.org/) for more info.

Two important things to note

> 1. In Java, multiple class loaders can coexist and each class loader creates its own name space. Different class loaders can load different class files with the same class name
> 2. The JVM does not allow dynamically reloading a class. Once a class loader loads a class, it cannot reload a modified version of that class during runtime. Thus, you cannot alter the definition of a class after the JVM loads it. However, the JPDA (Java Platform Debugger Architecture) provides limited ability for reloading a class

So you can achieve what you want in two different ways.

1. Create bytecode at runtime, write the class, use a custom classloader to create your pojo from the written class. `javassist` can help you for this, but this is way too complicated for me to consume at the moment.
2. Use `javassist` to modify an existing class and use reflection to set the values.

For option 2, the easier one, here is how you can achieve this.

1. Add `javassist` in your classpath. If you are using maven, add the following dependency in your `pom.xml`.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.21.0-GA</version>
</dependency>
```

1. Create a dummy empty pojo class that you need to work with. Let us call it `Pojo`.

```java
package com.test;

public class Pojo {
   //Nothing in the source file.
}
```

2. Modify the class body to add the fields from the `HashMap`. Here is a sample of how I did it using the map you gave.

```java
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("firstname", "John");
        map.put("lastname", "Doe");

        ClassPool cp = ClassPool.getDefault();
        
        CtClass cc = cp.get("com.test.Pojo");

        // Used for non-primitive data types. If primitive, use CtClass.<inttype, floattype, etc..>
        CtClass strClass = ClassPool.getDefault().get("java.lang.String");

        //Iterate and add all the fields as per the keys in the map
        Iterator<String> iterator = map.keySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = iterator.next();
            CtField field = new CtField(strClass, key, cc);
            field.setModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC);
            cc.addField(field);
        }

        // Instantiate from the updated class
        Class<Pojo> clazz = cc.toClass();
        Pojo newInstance = clazz.newInstance();

        //Use the map again to set the values using reflection.
        iterator = map.keySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = iterator.next();
            newInstance.getClass().getField(key).set(newInstance, map.get(key));
        }
```

3. `newInstance` is the instance of `Pojo` but with fields added based on keys of the map and set based on the values in the map. A simple test to print the `newInstance` using jackson `ObjectMapper` yields this.

```java
ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String writeValueAsString = objMapper.writeValueAsString(newInstance);
System.out.println(writeValueAsString);
```

> {"firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe"}

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

If you want to add get/set methods, you can create methods using `CtMethod` in `javassist`. However, you can only access them using reflection since these methods are added at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16430704/263597) in a similar question,  using Jackson objectMapper.convertvalue method seems most reasonable.

Comment: this does not answer my question because I don't know what my POJO will be!